# ObservableCollection showing items in incorrect order after Clear

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, observablecollection

I have a `ObservableCollection` where I add items and occasionally `Clear`.
Then there is reactive pipeline where the idea is to have current contents of the ObservableCollection in insertion order.

Before doing the first `Clear`, everything works. The items are in correct order.
However after doing `Clear`, order at the pipeline is not correct. Sometimes added items end up as the first, sometimes as the last.

```cs
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Item> = new(new List<Item>());

collection
  .ToObservableChangeSet(x => x)
  .ToCollection()
  .Do(coll =>
      // I want to have correct order of the items here.
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"---");
                foreach (var x in coll)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"x={x.Timestamp}");
                }
            })
  })
  ...
  .Subscribe(...)

// do some Adds and Clears to collection
```

Comment: Without doing any research, I would guess that `ToObservableChangeSet` makes no guarantees about the order in which the items are returned. The fact that a method does something most of the time or even all of the time is not a good reason to assume that it will always do so unless it is documented to do so, because it's possible that the implementation may change and stop working that way in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing this change it seems to work correctly:

```cs
.ToObservableChangeSet(x => x)
```

to

```cs
.ToObservableChangeSet()
```